# GUI thread detecting in the Qt library

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I need to know in the context of which thread my function is running, is it main GUI thread or some worker thread.

I can't use a simple solution to store QThread pointer in the main function and compare it to QThread::currentThread() because I'm writing a library and I do not have access to the main function. I can of course create InitMyLibary() function and require library user to call it in the context of the GUI thread but I'm **really** against this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you have Qt in the lib you can ask for the thread of the application object.  The application object is alway living in the main gui thread.

```
void fooWorker()
{
    const bool isGuiThread = 
        QThread::currentThread() == QCoreApplication::instance()->thread();

}
```

Comment: correct: QCoreApplication::instance()->thread(). I would also check for instance() == 0.