# Detect that "I'm running" in Qt GUI event thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have this function to update some GUI stuff:

```
void SavedConnections::renderList()
{
  // Do GUI stuff! Must run in Qt thread!!!
    ...
}
```

I need to ensure that this function isn't called from other threads. What I plan to do is to defer it into event loop and raise a warning:

```
void SavedConnections::renderList()
{ 
  if(!this_thread_is_Qt_GUI_thread()) {
    qDebug()<< "Warning: GUI operation attempted from non GUI thread!\n";
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new UpdateGUIEvent());
    return;
  }
  // Do GUI stuff! Must run in Qt thread!!!
    ...
}
```

This pattern is also very convenient to make methods that are guaranteed to run asynchronously in GUI thread without any ugly syntax. [I already asked similar question about Java's ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34798891/607407).

Comment: I wouldn't consider this being a duplicate of [the question it was marked as such](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977653/gui-thread-detecting-in-the-qt-library). Well, technically it is, but it's 2016 and the other question was from 2009 (Qt 4), where the main thread was the GUI thread. Today, in Qt 5, this is no longer the case, so the solution wouldn't have worked here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check if the current thread is the thread your object lives in:

```
if (QThread::currentThread() != this->thread()) {
   // Called from different thread
}
```

Note that *this might not be the main GUI-Thread*! It is the thread `this` lives in (see [QObject Thread affinity)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity). If you don't change it using `QObject::moveToThread`, it is the thread the object was created in.

This is also what `QCoreApplication::postEvent` uses to determine into which thread the event should be posted. The targeted Thread must run a `QEventLoop` to respond to the event.

So checking for the main-GUI-Thread (`qApp->thread()`), but posting to `this`'s thread might not work, if your object does not live in the main-GUI-Thread. However, if you do GUI stuff there, it should anyway live in the GUI-Thread