# Change affinity of an Object from a QThread to Main GUI Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I have a Qt GUI application which contains some classes and a main. For one of the computationally heavy writing operation i created a a `QThread`as a class member. Something like this:

```
//class members
std::unique_ptr<QThread> m_savingThread;
std::unique_ptr<DiffClass> m_controller;

connect(this, &SomeClass::saveAll, m_controller.get(), &DiffClass::saveToAll, Qt::QueuedConnection);    
connect(m_controller.get(), &DiffClass::done, m_savingThread.get(), &QThread::quit);

void SomeClass::saveToFile()
{
    //Saving thread
    qDebug() << "From main thread:" << QThread::currentThreadId();

    m_controller->moveToThread(m_savingThread.get());
    m_savingThread->start();

    qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string");
    emit saveAll(someString);
 }
```

The above code works fine. But i need the `m_controller` object back to the main GUI thread once the saving operation is finished. I could find something similar 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018713/detect-that-im-running-in-qt-gui-event-thread?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Briefly, it states that since `QThread` can only "push" the object into a thread, i need to push it again into the main thread from the current worker thread.

```
void DiffClass::saveToAll(someString)
{
    qDebug() << "From worker thread:" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    /*saving operation*/
    moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread()); //Error QCoreApplication has no member thread()
    emit done();
}
```

Is there a way to change the affinity of the object back to the main thread?

**EDIT 1:** My `connect` to `saveToAll` is a QueuedConnection.

Comment: You *definitely* have `#include <QApplication>`?  I ask because `QApplication::instance()` returns a `QCoreApplication *`, so I would expect the error message to be `QCoreApplication has no member thread()`.

Comment: Sorry thats a typo....you're right.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, why would you want to switch thread affinity back and forth? There doesn't seem to be a practical side to this.

Other than that, it should be possible to change it to another threat, the condition is that the object has no parent and the `moveToThread()` is invoked from the current affinity thread.

You can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` with `Qt::QueuedConnection` specified from any thread to schedule a slot execution from the current affinity thread, which will change affinity from the right thread to whatever thread you pass as a parameter.

But seeing how you try to change it from inside the class, that should work as expected, as long as `saveToAll()` is invoked via the signal/slot mechanism (rather than directly from just about any thread).

```
//Error QCoreApplication has no member thread()
```

It most certainly does according to the documentation.

Comment: The reason why i need to switch is my `m_controller` is attached to whole lot of other slots. My save function is triggered occassionally by the user but since its a heavy process it freezes my GUI till the operation is completed. So, i need the object to run on a thread just for this process.

Comment: Well, in that case you should consider a dedicated object and thread for that functionality alone. Moving it back and forth is not a good idea. Don't invite trouble.

Comment: You're right! But can't do it either since my object holds all the relevant data for writing the file.

Comment: You can access any object data from any thread. If there is danger of race conditions, simply use a mutex to protect the relevant data access.

Comment: Yes `saveToAll()` is invoked using signal/slot. Moreover, i have the same issue with `moveToThread(qApp->thread())`.

Comment: *my object holds all the relevant data for writing the file* - Assuming your data is stored with Qt classes that obey [Implicit Sharing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html#list-of-classes), send the data from your class to the saving object on the 2nd thread, via signal / slots. As they use [COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), this will be efficient, regardless of the size of data, so long as the data is never changed by the receiving object.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Well..i can see i have a lot to learn. I guess it won't work in my case because my `m_controller` inherits `QObject` and it doesn't have copy constructor nor it allows subclass copy constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why this is an issue. It has to inherit QObject to use signals and slots. What difference does the lack of the copy constructor make to pass the data, between threads, with the signal / slot mechanism?

Comment: ok may be i am confused how it is implmented. In this [Implicit Sharing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html#list-of-classes) it shows 2 instances need to share the data using `=` which is not allowed for `QObject` and moreover i am using a `unique_ptr` which again prohibits copying. Did i miss something? Or could you please post a small snippet.